# C# pass additional parameter to an event handler while binding the event at the run time

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods, parameters, arguments

I have a link button which have a regular click event :

```
protected void lnkSynEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

And I bind this event at the runtime :

```
lnkSynEvent.Click += new EventHandler(lnkSynEvent_Click);
```

Now I need the function to accept additional argument:

```
protected void lnkSynEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, DataTable dataT)
{
}
```

And pass the same as parameter while binding this event :

```
lnkSynEvent.Click += new EventHandler(lnkSynEvent_Click, //somehow here);
```

Not sure how to achieve this.
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Vishal

Comment: Where is the DataTable going to come from?

Comment: @PaulieWaulie its there where I am binding the event.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use anonymous delegate for that:

```
lnkSynEvent.Click += 
         new EventHandler((s,e)=>lnkSynEvent_Click(s, e, your_parameter));
```

Comment: WOW worked like a charm, thanks @alex, tough I am not much famalier with anonymous delegates yet.

Comment: You should mark this answer as correct. This may help others.

Comment: Simply you can write like this


Object.SomeEvent+= (sender,e)=>SomeEventHandler(sender, e, "Data");

///
And define your event handler like this

void SomeEventHandler(object sender, SomeEventArgs e, string data);

Comment: Alex, and how can we remove that? simply with `lnkSynEvent.Click -=new EventHandler( ...` ?

Comment: @alex: As *T.Todua* stated, how do you unsubscribe from it?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know exactly when it's changed, but now it's even easier!

```
lnkSynEvent.Click += (s,e) => lnkSynEvent_Click(s, e, your_parameter);
```

Comment: This actually worked better in my scenario as i needed to map an expected EventHandler<a,b> to EventHandler<a,b,c>. The accepted answer did not resolve this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

All answers above seem to be fine, but I have discovered one pitfall which is not so obvious and it took some time to figure out what is going on, so I wanted to share it.

Assume that `myList.Count` returns 16.

In the following case, `OnValueChangeWithIndex(p1, p2, i)` will always be called with **i = 16**.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    myList[i].OnValueChange += (p1, p2) => OnValueChangeWithIndex(p1, p2, i);
}
```

To avoid that, you would need to initialize a new variable inside of the loop, then pass the new variable to the function.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    int index = i;
    myList[i].OnValueChange += (p1, p2) => OnValueChangeWithIndex(p1, p2, index);
}
```

---

> Closures close over variables, not over values.

[Closing over the loop variable considered harmful, part one](https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/)

Answer (score 2):

by use of delegate:

```
lnkbtnDel.Click += delegate(object s, EventArgs e1) { 
                 Dynamic_Click(s, e1, lnkbtnDel.ID); 
               };`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
EventHandler myEvent = (sender, e) => MyMethod(myParameter);//my delegate

myButton.Click += myEvent;//suscribe
myButton.Click -= myEvent;//unsuscribe

private void MyMethod(MyParameterType myParameter)
{
 //Do something
}
```